# Is there a way to execute commands after file changed?

Tags: jekyll

I know that jekyll can auto generate site after files changes with `jekyll build --watch`. But can I execute bash scripts after the site generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a [jekyll plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) you can do anything during site generation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll provide my solution when I finish it.